# how to import data from a "export to excel" link on a web page?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to import a data table to my google sheets from a site which has the "export to excel" feature. I tried to use importdata, importhtml, importjson, importxml. none of these are working.

https://stockrow.com/api/companies/BSTC/financials.xlsx?d=y&s=income

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: that link is returning a file, not 'data'...